# Java Runtime.exec() works for some command but not others

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, command-line

I am doing an exercise related to Runtime.exec(), I understand that Runtime.exec is not a shell interpreter, that's why I execute "bash -c 'command'" instead, but for some reason, I can execute commands like ls `bash -c 'ls'` but not echo or redirection or multiple commands. These does not work:

```
bash -c 'echo 1234'
bash -c 'ls > abc'
bash -c 'ls;id'
bash -c 'ls -al'
```

Here is my java code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class runtime {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        String cmd = args[0];
        System.out.println(cmd);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
        String disr = dis.readLine();
        while ( disr != null ) {
                System.out.println("Out: " + disr);
                disr = dis.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I run the above commands with the syntax:
`java runtime "bash -c 'command'"`

This works:

```
$ java runtime "bash -c 'ls'"
bash -c 'ls'
Out: Main.class
Out: Main.java
Out: runtime.class
Out: runtime.java
```

I am using openjdk 11.0.15 on Ubuntu 20.04 and zsh.
Can anyone tell me why Runtime doesn't work in this case? Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest that you put a breakpoint in `exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)` and see what the tokenizer is doing to your string.

Comment: I will do some debug later, right now I haven't set up a debug environment yet. @tgdavies

Comment: @user16320675 If I do that, then "bash -c 'ls > abc'" will be broken into several args in the main args parameter. I have to use quote so that ```String cmd = args[0];``` have the value of "String cmd = args[0];" (without the quotes)

Comment: @user16320675 I will try the overload you suggested tomorrow, I will update the results here, thank you!

Comment: Worth mentioning is that this works: ```$ java runtime "bash -c 'ls'"
bash -c 'ls'
Out: Main.class
Out: Main.java
Out: runtime.class
Out: runtime.java```

Comment: The thing you said about it must be broken in bash makes sense, thank you again!! But why doesn't this works: ```java runtime "bash -c 'id;ls'"``` ?

Comment: Switch from `args[0]` to just passing all of `args`, and change `java runtime 'bash -c "whatever"'` to `java runtime bash -c "whatever"` and you're in a much better place.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I understand how and why my scripts doesn't work now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of shell parsing.

These are all concepts that **the OS just does not have**:

- The concept of 'every space separates one argument from another (and the command from the list of arguments'). The concept that a single string can possibly run anything, in fact; at the OS level that's just not what the 'run this thing' API looks like. When you type commands on the command prompt, your shell app is 'interpreting' these strings into a command execution request.
- The concept of figuring out that `bash` means `/bin/bash`, i.e. `$PATH` resolution.
- The concept that `*.txt` is supposed to refer to all files that ends in `.txt`.
- The concept that `$FOO` should be replaced with the value of the environment variable 'FOO'
- The concept that `;` separates 2 commands, and it's supposed to run both.
- The concept that single and double quotes escape things. "Escape things" implies that things can cause interpretation to happen. The OS interprets **nothing**, therefore there's nothing to escape. Obvious, then, that the OS doesn't know what `'` is, or `"`.
- That `>foo` means: Please set the standard output of the spawned process such that it sends it all to file 'foo'.
- In windows shells, that `@` in front of the command means 'do not echo the command itself'. This and many other things are shellisms: `/bin/bash` does that, maybe `/bin/zsh` does something else. Windows's built in shell thing definitely is quite different from bash!

Instead, an OS simply wants you to provide it a full path to an executable along with a list of strings, and pick targets for standard in, standard out, and standard err. It does **no processing on any of that**, just starts the process you named, and passes it the strings verbatim.

You're sort of half there, as you already figured out that e.g. `ls >foo` cannot work if you execute it on its own, but it can work if you tell bash to execute it. As ALL of that stuff in the above list? Your shell does that.

It gets more complicated: Turning `*.txt` into `foo.txt bar.txt` is a task of bash and friends, e.g. if you attempted to run: `ls '*.txt'` it does not work. But on windows, it's **not** the shell's job; the shell just passes it verbatim to `dir`, and it is the command's job to undo it. What a mess, right? Executing things is hard!

So, what's wrong here? Two things:

- Space splitting isn't working out.
- Quote application isn't being done.

When you write:

```
bash -c 'ls >foo'
```

in a bash shell, bash has to first split this up, into a command, and a list of arguments. Bash does so as follows:

- Command: `bash`
- arg1: `-c`
- arg2: `ls >foo`

It knows that `ls >foo` isn't 2 arguments because, effectively, "space" is the bash operator for: "... and here is the next argument", and with quotes (either single or double), the space becomes a literal space instead of the '... move to next argument ...' operator.

In your code, you ask bash to run java, and then java to run bash. So, bash first does:

- cmd: `java`
- arg1: `bash -c 'ls >foo'`

With the same logic at work. Your java app then takes that entire string (that's `args[0]`: `"bash -c 'ls >foo'"`), and you then feed it to a method you should never use: `Runtime.exec()`. Always use ProcessBuilder, and always use the list-based form of it.

Given that you're using the bad method, you're now asking **java** to do this splitting thing. After all, if you just tell the OS verbatim, please run `"bash -c 'ls >foo'"`, the OS dutifully reports: "I'm sorry, but file `./bash -c ;ls >foo'` does not exist", because **it does not processing at all**". This is unwieldy so java's `exec()` method is a disaster you should never use: Because people are confused about this, it tries to do some extremely basic processing, except every OS and shell is different, java does not know this, so it does a really bad job at it.

Hence, **do not use it**.

In this case, java doesn't realize that those quotes mean it shouldn't split, so java tells the OS:

Please run:

- cmd: `/bin/bash` (java DOES do path lookup; but you should avoid this, do not use relative path names, you should always write them out in full)
- arg1: `-c`
- arg2: `'ls`
- arg3: `>foo'`

and now you understand why this is just going completely wrong.

Instead, you want java to tell the OS:

- cmd: `/bin/bash`
- arg1: `-c`
- arg2: `ls >foo`

Note: `ls >foo` needs to be one argument, and NOTHING in the argument should be containing quotes, anywhere. The reason you write:

```
/bin/bash -c 'ls >foo'
```

In bash, is because you [A] want bash not to treat that space between `ls` and `>foo` as an arg separator (you want `ls >foo` to travel to `/bin/bash` as one argument), and [B] that you want `>foo` to just be sent to the bash you're spawning and not to be treated as 'please redirect the output to file foo' at the current shell level.

Runtime.exec isn't a shell, so the quotes stuff? Runtime.exec has no idea.

This means more generally your plan of "I shall write an app where the entire argument you pass to it is just run" is oversimplified and can never work unless you write an entire quotes and escaper analyser for it.

An easy way out is to take the input, write it out to a shell script on disk, set the exec flag on it, and always run `/bin/bash -c /path/to/script-you-just-wrote`, sidestepping any need to attempt to parse anything in java: Let bash do it.

The ONE weird bizarro thing I cannot explain, is that literally passing `'ls'` to `/bin/bash -c`, with quotes intact, DOES work and runs ls as normal, but `'ls *'` does not, perhaps because now bash thinks you want executable file `/bin/ls *` which obviously does not exist (a star cannot be in a file name, or at least, that's not the ls executable, and it's not an alias for the ls built-in). At any rate, you want to pass `ls` without the quotes.

Let's try it!

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class runtime {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        pb.command("/bin/bash", "-c", "echo 1234");
//        pb.command("/bin/bash", "-c", "'echo 1234'");
        Process p = pb.start();
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
        String disr = dis.readLine();
        while ( disr != null ) {
                System.out.println("Out: " + disr);
                disr = dis.readLine();
        }
        int errCode = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exit code: " + errCode);
    }
}
```

The above works fine. Replace the `.command` line with the commented out  variant and you'll notice it does not work at all, and you get an error. On my mac I get a '127' error; perhaps this is bash reporting back: I could not find the command you were attempting to execute. 0 is what you're looking for when you invoke waitFor: That's the code for 'no errors'.

Comment: *but 'ls \*' does not, perhaps because now bash thinks you want executable file /bin/ls \** That would probably be the equivalent of running `ls \*` in the terminal would it not?

Comment: I think you meant to say: `ls\ \*` - I think that's what's happening, yeah.

Comment: Actually i didn't ;) That would be different slightly but also 'worse'

Comment: Mostly right; `Runtime.exec` doesn't do escaping, redirection or piping, variable substitution or command substitution, or globbing; Unix shells handle all of those and Windows CMD all but the last two. But both Unix (nowadays, though not long-ago versions) and Windows DO $PATH or %PATH% search, respectively. (Windows additionally tries the current dir and system dir, though usually the latter is already in %PATH%.)